# jQuery datepicker work with select boxes

Tags: jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement a jQuery UI datepicker to work with a series of select boxes instead of an input text box. The reason is that the select boxes are auto-generated and I cannot change that code, hence I cannot change it to input text box.

This is a typical datepicker and I can get this to work.

[image]

However, for us, we need to make it work with this:

[image]

Here's the HTML for this:

```
<div class="DetailRow">
    <div class="Label">
         <span class="Required">*</span>Tour Begin Date:
    </div>
    <div class="Value">
        <select id="EventDateMonth" name="EventDate[Mth]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; ">
            <option value="-1">---</option><option value="1">Jan</option><option value="2">Feb</option><option value="3">Mar</option><option value="4">Apr</option><option value="5">May</option><option value="6">Jun</option><option value="7">Jul</option><option value="8">Aug</option><option value="9">Sep</option><option value="10">Oct</option><option value="11">Nov</option><option value="12">Dec</option>
        </select>
        <select id="EventDateDay" name="EventDate[Day]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; ">
            <option value="-1">---</option><option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option><option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option><option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option>
        </select>
        <select id="EventDateYear" name="EventDate[Yr]" class="CalendarSelectSmall" style="margin-bottom:3px; ">
            <option value="-1">---</option><option value="2012">2012</option>
        </select>
        <div>
            (Must be before 31st Dec 2012)
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

code suggestion has been provided at http://forum.jquery.com/topic/using-datepicker-22-2-2011

Answer (score 0):

erhaps you could call a datepicker attached to a hidden input box,with say the jQuery datepicker icon trigger. When the calendar is clicked you have you then need to substring the values inserted into the hidden text box into the appropriate dropdown.

[jQuery icon trigger example](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#icon-trigger)